# Make first letter capital in sentence which is occuring after blank space and first letter by CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to update the letter case in the output. I am having this type of input string:

**Input:**

```
<style>
p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

p:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>


<p>HELLO I AM HERE</p>
```

**Current Output**

```
Hello i am here
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Hello I Am Here
```

The CSS is not working for me.

Comment: @steven you can do this with easily.please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<p>HELLO I AM HERE</p>`

Since your string is all capitalized, you can't really do it with CSS alone without tedious wrapping of each word in a `<span>` tag, but JS can do the trick:

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
  node.textContent = node.textContent.split(' ').map(function(word) {
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase();
  }).join(' ');
});
```

```html
<p class='test'>HELLO I AM HERE</p>
<p class='test'>HELLO I AM HERE AGAIN</p>
<p class='test'>HELLO I AM HERE AGAIN AND AGAIN</p>
```

Comment: I have number of p with respect to class. How can i achieve this with js only.

Comment: @steven you can `querySelectorAll` the class, iterate through each reference and apply the above JS code to each.

Comment: Can you please create demo fiddle for me. Use data like this <p class="test">TEST HELLO</p><p class="test">TEST HELLO1</p>... and so on.

Comment: @steven I'll update the Stack Snippet. Give me a moment.

Comment: I don't want console. I want it changes text to desired place also.

Comment: ?? CSS can do this since ever : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform  CSS level1 https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#text-transform

Comment: @GCyrillus Doesn't work if everything is uppercase. Try it yourself.

Comment: @ timolawl Thanks working for me..... already accepted ... :)

Comment: Yep, just noticed about uppercase text :(

Answer (score 0):

```
text-transform: capitalize
```

Is what you want.

**Edit**: if your initial string is all uppercase you may have to make it lowercase with javascript first...

Comment: That doesn't work with text that's all uppercase -> https://jsfiddle.net/Lupe1eeb/

Comment: Actually this wouldn't work as his input is already in uppercase that wouldn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a straight answer:

pass input text into `getCapitalize` below javascript function and  it will return you expected output-

```js
var text = $(".capitalize").text();

var formattedText = getCapitalize(text); // use of function

$(".capitalize").text(formattedText);  // assign formatted text the container


 
function getCapitalize(text){  //formatter function
  
     var textArray = text.split(" ");

     for(i= 0; i<textArray.length; i++){
  
     textArray[i] = textArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + textArray[i].substr(1).toLowerCase();

     }
     return textArray.join(" ");      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="capitalize">HELLO I AM HERE.</p>
```

***Hoping this will help you:)***

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily with this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "p.tolower" ).each(function( index ) {
   var text= $(this).text().toLowerCase();
   $(this).html(text);
  });});
```

```css
p.tolower{text-transform: capitalize;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='tolower'>HELLO I AM HERE</p>
<p class='tolower'>HELLO I AM HERE AGAIN</p>
<p class='tolower'>HELLO I AM HERE AGAIN AND AGAIN</p>
```

Comment: It is always print same output : Hello I Am Here.....

Comment: my mistake :) i will update you 1 min

Comment: @steven now it's working fine please check